# How to get the maximum value group by column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

Hi and good day everyone, i'm here to ask currently i'm trying to get total quantity as expect below table. The total quantity will auto calculate the total quantity group by data column until the data is changed to others data

Previous Result:

```
Id   Name      Data        
----------------------------
1    A       A_data_1          
2    A       A_data_2         
3    A       A_data_3          
4    B       B_data_1        
5    B       B_data_2           
6    C       C_data_1
```

Expected Result:

```
Id   Name      Data        Total Quantity
-----------------------------------------
1    A       A_data_1          null
2    A       A_data_2          null
3    A       A_data_3            3
4    B       B_data_1          null
5    B       B_data_2            2
6    C       C_data_1            1
```

I have try to use group by but it seems not working for me

Comment: You need the max value for each group ? With group I mean based on the `Name` column. What MySQL version are you using ?

Comment: plz post what you have tried and what is the error

Comment: @ErgestBasha yup, version 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the expected result you need to use left join with the subquery which get the total count for each group.

Try:

```
   select test.id,test.name,test.`data`,total_count
   from test
   left join ( select max(id) as id ,name,count(name) as total_count
                from test 
                group by name  
              ) as t1 on t1.id=test.id;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uLPPE1DoKjKYBoSXfKahJN/28

Comment: I think the question a bit confusing, initially there was no total_quantity in the table, so i want to achieve the same result as the picture like above

Comment: i already updated to the latest

Comment: Thank you for the answer, appreciated!!! Can u leave linkedin contact or anything, so i have a guidances in future. I really need to improve my sql skill with good mentor if u don't mind

Comment: Thank you Ergest, can i have some tips on how to improve sql skills and the resources u learn thru the years. I have no ideas on it

Comment: @oscar this https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-basics/ is a site I like, or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-common-mysql-queries/ . Just keep practicing